# On hover show div, position from bottom of main div

Tags: html, css

Im trying with css to show another div to my main div but to position from bottom of main div, and not as block as im testing with my code.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
   <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/></a>
    <div id="hidden">
      <h2><a href="">Link1</h2>
      <h2><a href="">Link2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
width: 540px;
border: 1px solid #eee;
text-align:center;
}

#hidden {
display:none;
border: 4px solid #eee;
}

#main:hover > #hidden {
display:block;
}
```

What i like is to have something like image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q41JG.png

Comment: plz create http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#main {
    width: 540px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
#hidden {
    display:none;
    border: 4px solid #eee;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
}
#main:hover > #hidden {
    display:block;
}
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/cyV7z/4/)

**Explanation:**
Firstly I made the position of the `#main` div relative to the body and then I made the position of `#main`'s child, `#hidden`, absolute positioned so this will move `#hidden` with the `#main` as `#hidden`'s parent is now relatively positioned with the document body and yes, I changed the bottom margin to 0 so that it could stick to the bottom of the `#main` div.

Comment: @user3212855 fiddle also updated. Now it's correct, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted was this wanting some more code!

It required the position attribute code! By using which, you can place an element over another element. Since otherwise it is not possible!

Here is the fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/R89A8/

I changed the CSS to this:

```
#main {
width: 540px;
border: 1px solid #eee;
text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

#hidden {
display:none;
border: 4px solid #eee;
}

#main:hover > #hidden {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

You can see that I have just added `position: value` and `bottom: value` attribute to your code.

Second thing, the HTML is as:

```
<div id="main">
   <a href="#"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/></a>
    <div id="hidden">
        <h2><a href="">Link1</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Link2</a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that you are required to close every opening tag to make your HTML a valid HTML!

And excuse me, I have not given a width and height value to the box, you can set it yourself!

For more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
#hidden {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background:white;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/z2wc2/)